# How can I insert something different than the selected item with Closure Autocompleter?

Tags: google-closure-library

I would like to use the [ui.Autocomplete.Basic](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_ui_AutoComplete_Basic.html). I have some values and additional information to these values. I would like the additional information to be displayed, but it should not be inserted. Is this possible? How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. You'd have to construct the base `goog.ui.AutoComplete` yourself (much like the `goog.ui.AutoComplete.Basic` constructor does), then provide a custom implementation (subclass) of `goog.ui.AutoComplete.InputHandler`. Specifically, you'd want to override the `selectRow` function to do what you want with the `row` parameter. The default implementation is as follows:

```
...selectRow = function(row,opt_multi) {
  this.setTokenText(row.toString(), opt_multi);
  return false;
};
```

This would be quite a bit more straightforward if the `goog.ui.AutoComplete.Basic` constructor took an optional input handler. That might be a reasonable thing to request at http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/issues/list if this strategy works.

Comment: Hi nullptr, thanks for your answer.
Here is a script that works: http://pastebin.com/rUKxt8Yp

Comment: Good to see that it works. I would still suggest subclassing `InputHandler`, the strategy you chose would override the behavior for all users of the class.